# Convert object with nullable fields to an object with non-nullable fields or null

Tags: kotlin

I have a object returned by an API, that has different nullable fields.
I want to create a another object with non-nullable fields or return null if it is not possible. What is the language idiom that suits that scenario best? Currently I'm using `?.let {}` and it looks pretty ugly:

```
fun convertAnswer(userAnswer: AnswerGson, answerResponse: AnswerResponseGson,
                  correctAnswerText: String): AnswerResponseUi? {
    return userAnswer.id?.let { userAnswerId ->
        userAnswer.text?.let { userAnswerText ->
            answerResponse.answer?.id?.let { correctAnswerId ->
                answerResponse.points?.let { points ->
                    answerResponse.discount?.let { discount ->
                        answerResponse.booster?.let { booster ->
                            return AnswerResponseUi(userAnswerId, correctAnswerId, userAnswerText,
                                    correctAnswerText, points, discount, booster.name ?: "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your classes `AnswerGson` and `AnswerResponseGson` have their properties declared as `val`, you can convert your code to something like this:

```
fun convertAnswer(userAnswer: AnswerGson, answerResponse: AnswerResponseGson,
                  correctAnswerText: String): AnswerResponseUi? {
    if (userAnswer.id == null ||
        userAnswer.text == null ||
        answerResponse.discount == null ||
        answerResponse.points == null ||
        answerResponse.booster == null ||
        answerResponse.answer == null ||
        answerResponse.answer.id == null
    ) return null

    return AnswerResponseUi(userAnswer.id, answerResponse.answer.id, userAnswer.text,
                            correctAnswerText, answerResponse.points,
                            answerResponse.discount, answerResponse.booster.name ?: "")
}
```

This example uses [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts): the compiler analyses the control flow and proves that if the last statement is reached then none of the values checked above are `null`.

These checks are not applied to safe dereference chains, and I had to check first `answerResponse.answer` and only then `answerResponse.answer.id`.

---

If you have `var` properties, smart casts cannot be applied because the value might change after it is checked.

In this case, you can still reduce the nesting in your code by extracting the values into local variables and checking them at the same time:

```
fun convertAnswer(userAnswer: AnswerGson, answerResponse: AnswerResponseGson,
                  correctAnswerText: String): AnswerResponseUi? {
    val answerId = userAnswer.id ?: return null
    val correctAnswerId = answerResponse.answer?.id ?: return null
    val userAnswerText = userAnswer.text ?: return null
    val points = answerResponse.points ?: return null
    val discount = answerResponse.discount ?: return null
    val booster = answerResponse.booster ?: return null

    return AnswerResponseUi(answerId, correctAnswerId, userAnswerText,
                            correctAnswerText, points,
                            discount, booster.name ?: "")
}
```

And, as [@mfulton26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26) noticed, you can even inline these variables (works for `val`s as well):

```
fun convertAnswer(userAnswer: AnswerGson, answerResponse: AnswerResponseGson,
                  correctAnswerText: String): AnswerResponseUi? {
    return AnswerResponseUi(userAnswer.id ?: return null, 
                            answerResponse.answer?.id ?: return null, 
                            userAnswer.text ?: return null,
                            correctAnswerText, 
                            answerResponse.points ?: return null,
                            answerResponse.discount ?: return null, 
                            (answerResponse.booster ?: return null).name ?: "")
}
```

Comment: Wow... I just realized that all of those local variables can even be inlined if you don't want them. e.g. `... return AnswerResponseUi(userAnswer.id ?: return null, answerResponse.answer?.id ?: return null, ...`

Comment: Readability is key, so do not try to inline everything ;) But this is impressive indeed!